# XE5 Android tswitch events not thread safe

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am changing a label in tswitch.onchange, and app gets unstable like it hangs. this seems to be the case in sensors to. I have to use a timer to update screen with new informations. Are using an Android unit. Tablet and phone is not sensitive in the same manner for this. Anyone with other experience?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that FMX UI controls are thread safe? Where have you seen that stated?

Comment: All UIs - Android, iOS, Windows - should generally be accessed from the main thread (UI thread) only. It's very rare for a UI layer to be threadsafe. So, if this event runs in another thread context, use a thread mechanism to update the label. TThread.Synchronize is a possibility; there are lots more.

Comment: When debugging on win32 compilation (android do not debug, Delphi exits debugging as soon as app starts) debug focus is lost on label.text:='some'; Not every times but most. In W32 app seems to continue as normal, but on Android it some times hang up for a long time, mostly a shorter time. When using onclick this is not a problem.

Comment: In XE5, [TThread.Synchronize() and TThread.Queue() do not work correctly in FireMonkey](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123579)